# Can Robinson arithmetic prove any interesting theorems?

Tags: lo.logic, theories-of-arithmetic

The motivation for my question is I'm curious whether studying Robinson arithmetic can be fruitful in the same sense as studying group theory. Robinson arithmetic is so weak that there are many structures that satisfy its axioms, just like there are many structures that satisfy the group axioms. But are there any interesting theorems we can prove about all such structures?

By interesting, I mean something that wouldn't be obvious to someone who has just learned how to count, but not because the statement is absurdly long and complex.

Since Robinson arithmetic is $\Sigma_1$-complete, I'm excluding $\Sigma_1$ statements.

Comment: Other than it's original usage and derivatives? Which version of Robinson arithmetic are you thinking of?

Comment: As far as I understand, its original usage was for proving theorems about it, not for proving theorems within it. I'm thinking of the first-order theory whose axioms are those of PA without induction with the axiom that every number is either 0 or the successor of some number.

Comment: "Those of PA" is the ambiguous part. If you're more specific you will see that there are lots and lots of models! (Especially if you stick to the basics and don't fall into the semiring trap.) I think they're interesting but I can only remember a couple of uses, both would perhaps seem sketchy to you.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais what's the semiring trap? Does it pin down things super tightly?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think he is referring to the following. If I'm defining $\mathsf{PA}$ to an audience not interested in Robinson arithmetic, I'll say it's the nonnegative discrete ordered semiring axioms + the induction scheme. Throwing away induction then amounts to axioms saying that you're the nonnegative part of a discrete ordered ring. However, this is *much* stronger than Robinson arithmetic, which e.g. doesn't even prove that addition is commutative. The issue is that there are lots of ways to write $\mathsf{PA}=T+IndScheme$, which the slogan "$\mathsf{PA}-IndScheme=\mathsf{Q}$" ignores.

Comment: I don’t know what counts as interesting, but Robinson’s arithmetic proves all kinds of things of the form “Bertrand’s postulate and Sylvester’s theorem hold for all numbers from this and this definable cut”. (The definition of the cut *may* be fairly long, sure.)

Comment: Robinson’s arithmetic is Robinson’s arithmetic. Other theories of the form “a variant axiomatization of PA minus the induction schema” are not called and should not be called Robinson’s arithmetic. There is no need to confuse the OP on this front.